# Is McDonald's exempt from the HHS Contraception Mandate?

Tags: united-states, contraception, healthcare, mcdonalds

The President of Eden Foods, a natural and organic food distributor, recently wrote:

> The exemptions under the Act are illogical, inconsistent, and contributing factors to our lawsuit. For instance, McDonald's Inc. and 166 unions are exempt.
>
> [Statement from the President of Eden Foods - April 17th 2013](http://www.edenfoods.com/articles/view.php?articles_id=219)

I've seen [this](http://www.csnews.com/top-story-foodservice-nacs_clarifies_what_mcdonald_s_health_care_exemption_means_-57377.html) but it predates the letter by 3 years and might not be applicable since the final rules were only recently finalized.

**Is McDonald's exempt from the [HHS Contraception Mandate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraceptive_mandate_%28United_States%29)?**

Comment: It's changed, it used to be only 100% religious employers who only serve co-religionists. I think now it's just churches and dioceses who have a religious objection. (I don't know how McDonalds falls under that excemption)

Comment: Or the exceptions under the Act are illogical.

Comment: Right, that's why I'm asking the question.  The exemptions that were contentious were the religious exemptions. If MCD's gets a pass just because it's a corporate behemoth, that's pretty lame.  If Eden foods is basing it's court case off of old data, that's pretty lame too.  If I'm being led astray by a [National Catholic Register blogger](http://www.ncregister.com/blog/simcha-fisher/so-long-and-thanks-for-all-the-intersex-fish/) I want to let her know.

Answer (score 2):

According to an [article](http://www.csnews.com/top-story-foodservice-nacs_clarifies_what_mcdonald_s_health_care_exemption_means_-57377.html) from the National Association of Convenience Stores ([NACS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Association_of_Convenience_Stores)):

> "In simple terms these companies and unions applied for and received a
>   waiver that would allow them to continue offering 'limited benefit
>   plans' to their part-time, seasonal and temporary employees. The
>   waiver is for one year and only waives the portion of the law that
>   phases out annual limits. Waivers must be applied for each year until
>   2014 when the new health care exchanges are set up and these employers
>   and workers will have other insurance options,"

So, McDonald's "exemption" is a temporary waiver, and not specific to the birth control part of the bill.